# changing the page in a UIWebView dynamically

Tags: iphone, ios, jquery-mobile, uiwebview, navigation

I need some iPhone expertise..

I have a UIWebView which displays by jquery mobile pages..

I want to have two ios native buttons below the webview - 1. Home 2. Settings.

The home button is easy enough as when I drag the link from the button XCode it gives me the options of goHome, goBack, etc. However for my settings button I want it to go to a specific URL. I can't seem to find much on the web on how to do that. I have so far managed to avoid doing much in the ios world, but I think I can't get around this anymore. So if you can give me lowdown on how the buttonpressed event can flow to the UIWebView and change the page that'll be great! If it's easier I'll just zip up my xcode project.

I have seen many tutorials on how to create an iOS web browser but not have a bookmarks bar, which is similar functionality to what I need.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can load a specific URL to the UIWebView like following

```
[self.webview loadRequest: [NSURLRequest requestWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://www.google.com"]]];
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.. but I'm not sure where to put that line? When I select the button, from the 'Sent Events' I drag a line from 'touch up inside' to the UIWebView but then it only presents be with four options (goBack, goForward, reload, stopLoading). I don't know why they closed this question :(